# Understanding the $code parameter in Mage::app()

Tags: magento-1.9

In some code online I see the following line use quite often and I understand it is the `initialisation / bootstrapping` of the main magento class.

```
Mage::app()
```

And in some cases I have seen

```
Mage::app('admin')
```

The parameter is **$code** , which seems a little bit vague given the different code types in magento. Maybe this a store code?

**What would I put in this parameter and why?** ( for example , why would I use 'admin' instead of leaving it out - and are there any other options ).

Thanks so much , I really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 2):

The parameter is the code of the store view you are running.
Or it could be the code of the website you want to run if you set the second parameter as well. `Mage::app('website_code', 'website');`.
This will run the default store view from the provided website.
Calling `Mage::app()` without parameters is equivalent to calling it with the default store view from the default website you have set in your database.

There is also a catch.

Calling `Mage::app()` a second time in the same request will just return you the instance of the `Mage_Core_Model_App` with the store view that is already set in the first call.

Example:

```
Mage::app('store_view1'); //sets the context to store view with code `store_view1`.  
//other code here
Mage::app('store_view2');//just retruns the instance of `Mage_Core_Model_App` generated in the first call and DOES NOT set the context to store view with id `store_view2`.
```

Suggestion.
Use `Mage::app('admin')` only in standalone scripts that require actions done in the admin context. Like deleting a product or customer.